How can I make the interaction continous by constantly waiting user input?
I found this flag code online, but i would like to make it loop by starting another game after one finishes. How do I keep the bot in the context and keep waiting for inputs?
@bot.command(name='flags', description='Play a flag guessing game')
async def flag_game(ctx:commands.Context):
    """Start a flag guessing game."""
    # Randomly select a flag from the list.
    random_flag = random.choice(list(flags.keys()))

    # Send a "Drawing..." message with an emoji.
    drawing_message = await ctx.send("Drawing... :checkered_flag:")
    await ctx.reply("Flag Game Started")
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    # Wait for 3 seconds.
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

    # Edit the message to show the flag.
    flag_emoji = flags[random_flag]
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Flag Game', description=f"Here is the flag of one of the countries. What is the name of this country?")
    embed.add_field(name="Flag:", value=flag_emoji, inline=False)
    await drawing_message.edit(content=None, embed=embed)

    # Wait for the user's response.
    try:
        response = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author, timeout=30.0)

        # Check the response, ignoring case.
        if response.content.lower() == random_flag.lower():
            await ctx.send(f"Congratulations! Correct answer. It's the flag of {random_flag}.")  
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"Sorry, that's not the correct answer. The correct answer is {random_flag}.")

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Time for a response has expired. Game over.")
        embed.add_field(name="Flag:", value=flag_emoji, inline=False)
        await drawing_message.edit(content=None, embed=embed)
    else:
        return

It runs perfectly fine, but i would like to make it continuous by constantly starting a new game after one finishes.

What's the question here? What do you mean by making it continous. Add some more text to your question and clarify your goal.  Currently what you are trying to acvhieve is very vague

I love the fact that this code snippet came from another stack question and now it's improved and someone will probably ask another question on this one and someone will make another answer and so on... Original Code

If you are trying to bot to keep waiting for message events you already got that in your code.

response = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author, timeout=30.0)

I just wrapped it in a while loop with game_on boolean.
@bot.command(name='flags', description='Play a flag guessing game.')
async def flag_game(ctx:commands.Context):
    game_on = True

    # Send a "Drawing..." message with an emoji.
    drawing_message = await ctx.send("Drawing... :checkered_flag:")
    await ctx.reply("Flag Game Started")
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    # Wait for 3 seconds.
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

    # Keep playing until game is over
    while game_on:
        random_flag = random.choice(list(flags.keys())) #Pick random every turn
        flag_emoji = flags[random_flag]
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Flag Game', description=f"Here is the flag of one of the countries. What is the name of this country?")
        embed.add_field(name="Flag:", value=flag_emoji, inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)# drawing_message.edit(content=None, embed=embed)

        # Wait for the user's response.
        try:
            response = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author, timeout=30.0)

            # Check the response, ignoring case.
            if response.content.lower() == random_flag.lower():
                await ctx.send(f"Congratulations! Correct answer. It's the flag of {random_flag}.")
            elif response.content.lower() == "exit":
                await ctx.send("Exiting the game.")
                game_on = False
                continue
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"Sorry, that's not the correct answer. The correct answer is {random_flag}.")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("Time for a response has expired. Game over.")
            game_on = False
            continue

Now the game exits when you type "exit" or 30 seconds passes without message.
Accepting the answer closes the question.
